# Selecting same column list for different where conditions

Tags: sql-server, select, multiple-columns

I have a stored procedure returning same columns according to different parameters.

for example;

```
if name is not null
select a,b,c,d,e,f
from table1, table2, table3
where .....

if age is not null
select a,b,c,d,e,f
from table1, table2, table3,table4
where .....

if city is not null
select a,b,c,d,e,f
from table1,table3,table5
where .....
```

The problem is when I want to add/omit columns I will need to do it for every select.

Is there any way to keep column list once and use it for different where conditions?

Comment: I strongly advice you avoiding using the old select from a,b,c... instead start use the ansi INNER JOIN....

Comment: Table set is not same on different selects, so I do not want to include tables for no reason for different parameters. My question is similar to how to create overwrite function in C#? Different parameters but same return type.

Comment: Nevertheless I'm suggesting you to stop using old and not recommended syntax. Using FROM and listing the tables is discouraged for maybe more than 20 years now.

Comment: Ah, I got you now. No, it is not my real syntax, I am using Inner join between tables, it is just for demonstration of I am using different tables for different where statements and select is exactly same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use dynamic SQL

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(4000)
SET @sql = '
select a,b,c,d,e,f
from table1,table3,table5
where 1=1 '

IF @name IS NOT NULL
  SET @sql = @sql + ' AND name = ' + @city
IF @age IS NOT NULL
  SET @sql = @sql + ' AND age = ' + @age
IF @city IS NOT NULL
  SET @sql = @sql + ' AND city = ' + @city


EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer however, Wont it create performance issues? Then I will not able to use compiled query performance?

Comment: Do some testing but IMO it'll be negligible

Comment: I agree with @ThomasHaratyk. as a matter of fact so many selects could drive the query plans and statistics crazy. dynamic SQL is much more desirable in this case

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT -- select list here
.....
WHERE
   name= CASE WHEN @name IS NULL THEN name ELSE @name END  
   AND age= CASE WHEN @age IS NULL THEN age ELSE @age END  
   AND city= CASE WHEN @city IS NULL THEN city ELSE @city END
```

Comment: This would probably have been a valid suggestion if the table set had been fixed.